# Bitbucket repo clone with login credentials

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

I have a Basic git clone command to bitbucket in which I have to add Login credentials, is it possible to add Login credentials to a bitbucket git clone command?

```
https://myacc@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git
```

Something like this?

```
https://myacc@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git -Password "123"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+credentials+in+URL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can, with:

```
git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git
```

But this will save your credentials in the origin url in `.git/config`.
To avoid that you could change the origin afterwards 
`git remote set-url origin https://myacc@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git`

Comment: Do I Need to add the Project Name if in the git remove command if I start like this?`git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git MyApp` so should it be this? `git remote set-url origin https://myacc@bitbucket.org/myacc/app.git MyApp`

Comment: It should work the way I posted it. The project should already be included in the URL.

Comment: Ok thanks it seems to work, can you explain me this further I do not understand why this is an issue `But this will save your credentials in the origin url in .git/config.`

Comment: It does not have to be an isse.<br/>In your projects local `.git` folder is a config file, and whoever has access to this file will then have your credentials, as it stores the origin url in it. But if you are the only one on your PC with access to this file, then there is no issue.

Comment: What if password contains a `@` ?

Comment: @MarinosAn You can type %40 for @. More info: https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/07/git-calling-git-clone-using-password-with-special-character/